# JAVASCRIPT como centrar una imagen con window.innerWidth y window.innerHeight

Tags: javascript, height, width

tengo una imagen, y la idea es que cuando pinche sobre ella, colocarla al centro de la pantalla según el tamaño del navegador en ese momento por medio de javascript y `window.innerWidth y window.innerHeight`.

No puedo usar flexbox en este ejercicio, es para practicar los valores antes mencionados.
He probado un poco de todo pero no consigo centrar nada. A ojo si puedo hacerlo, pero obviamente no es la idea y es mala práctica.

```js
function ampliar() {
    var abuelo = document.querySelector(".abuelo");
    var nuevo = document.createElement("div"); // se crea el div que contendrá la capa gris
    nuevo.className= "capa"; // estilos al div creado
    nuevo.style.width=window.innerWidth+"px";
    nuevo.style.height=window.innerHeight+"px";
     
    var imagen = document.createElement("img");
    var src = "img/pajaro_grande.jpg";
    imagen.setAttribute("src",src);
    imagen.setAttribute("class","imagen")
    imagen.style.left=window.innerWidth;
  

   
    abuelo.appendChild(imagen);
    
    document.body.appendChild(nuevo);
    
    
    
    

  
   
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}


.capa{
    
    background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
    
    
    
}
.imagen{
   position: absolute;
   /* top y lef deben calcularse en JS */
   z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Ejercicio 22</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="ej22.css">
    <script src="ej22.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
    <div class="abuelo">
        <img src="img/pajaro_chico.jpg" alt="foto" onclick="ampliar()">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

El código lo tengo así, por desgracia no podréis ver la imagen, pero espero que os podáis hacer a la idea de lo que pretendo hacer.
Para centrar la imagen ampliada al centro de la pantalla, he probado con `imagen.style.left=window.innerWidth+"px"/2;` pero no lo coge, también he probado con `imagen.style.left=window.innerWidth+"px+50+"%";` pero tampoco. No sé si tengo el concepto equivocado, ¿se os ocurre algo?

Comment: Debes calcular `(ancho de ventana - ancho de imagen) / 2` para la propiedad `left` y la misma fórmula, pero con altura para la propiedad `top`.

Comment: Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que estás atacando el problema con las herramientas equivocadas. Usar `window.innerWidth` no es la solución correcta. Incluso cuando puede que te de resultado para una resolución específica, si el usuario cambia el tamaño de la ventana, tu página tendrá serios problemas en cuanto a ser "responsive".

Para lo que quieres hacer, lo mejor es usar `position: fixed` y unidades relativas de porcentaje. Cuando usas `position: fixed` las propiedades `top`, `left`, `right` y `bottom` se refieren al tamaño de la ventana de tu navegador, por lo que te será muy fácil centrar con ellas. Agrega a eso `transform: translate()` y tienes tu problema resuelto.

Te adjunto un ejemplo que puedes ejecutar desde acá donde, modificando un poco tu css y javascript conseguí lo que buscas.

```js
function ampliar() {
    var abuelo = document.querySelector(".abuelo");
    var nuevo = document.createElement("div"); // se crea el div que contendrá la capa gris
    nuevo.classList.add("capa"); // estilos al div creado
     
    var imagen = document.createElement("img");
    var src = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/duck-4080673-3383066.png";
    imagen.setAttribute("src",src);
    imagen.setAttribute("class","imagen")
  

    nuevo.appendChild(imagen);    
    document.body.appendChild(nuevo);
    
    nuevo.addEventListener("click", function(e){
      this.remove()
    })
}
```

```css
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.capa{
    background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height:100%;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2
}

.imagen{
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
  z-index: 20;
}
```

```html
<div class="abuelo">
  <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/duck-4080673-3383066.png" alt="foto" onclick="ampliar()">
</div>
```

Incluso cuando es mala práctica lo que buscas, te adjunto un ejemplo utilizando solo `window.innerWidth` y `window.innerHeight`.
Para que observes por ti mismo el problema que contrae esto, te invito a que pinches en la imagen con la ventana pequeña, y luego cambies a pantalla completa. Verás que usando esta vía no es para nada responsiva tu página.

```js
function ampliar() {
    var abuelo = document.querySelector(".abuelo");
    var nuevo = document.createElement("div"); // se crea el div que contendrá la capa gris
    nuevo.className= "capa"; // estilos al div creado
    nuevo.style.width=window.innerWidth+"px";
    nuevo.style.height=window.innerHeight+"px";
     
    var imagen = document.createElement("img");
    abuelo.appendChild(imagen);
    document.body.appendChild(nuevo);
    var src = "https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/duck-4080673-3383066.png";
    imagen.setAttribute("src",src);
    imagen.setAttribute("class","imagen")
    imagen.style.left = window.innerWidth/2 - imagen.clientWidth/2 +"px";
    imagen.style.top= window.innerHeight/2 - imagen.clientHeight/2 + "px";
  

   
  
}
```

```css
body{
    background-color: white;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

}

.capa{  
    background-color: rgb(184, 184, 184);
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
   
    opacity: 0.7;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 2;
}

.imagen{
   position: absolute;
   /* top y lef deben calcularse en JS */
   z-index: 7;
}
```

```html
<div class="abuelo">
  <img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/premium/png-256-thumb/duck-4080673-3383066.png" alt="foto" onclick="ampliar()">
</div>
```

Comment: Genial muchas gracias!